# html pattern phone number optional extenstion

Tags: regex, html

I am new to html and I'm trying to use pattern to validate a phone numbers.

The phone numbers may or not have an extension.

The phone numbers should have this format `999-999-9999 ext 99999999`.  I'm allow up to 8 digits for the extension. The validation works fine with this:

```
pattern="[0-9]{3}[ -][0-9]{3}[ -][0-9]{4}"
```

and validates correctly.  However when I try to add the extentsion to the pattern above:

```
pattern="[0-9]{3}[ -][0-9]{3}[ -][0-9]{4}[\ext][0-9]{8}"
```

then I can add characters in any part of the phone number.  I only want numbers in all parts of the phone number including the extension.

Comment: Can you post a bit more context for your code? not getting where this is coming from

Comment: Can you post some test case so that, I can make proper regex.

Answer (score 2):

Try `([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})( ext [0-9]{0,8})?`

Here I'm defining two groups, the first `([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})` captures the phone number as 3 digits followed by a dash, then three digits followed by a dash then four digits.

The second group, `( ext [0-9]{1,8})?`,  captures the extension match as a space followed by the text ext followed by between 1 to 8 digits. This second group could appear from zero to one time as specified by the `?`